# How do I efficiently map keys from one dataset based on values from other dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, data-transform

Assuming data frame 1 represents target country and list of source countries and data frame 2 represents the availability for all the countries, find all the pairs from data frame 1 where target country mapping is **TRUE** and source country mapping is **FALSE**:

**Dataframe 1 (targetId, sourceId):**
USA: China, Russia, India, Japan
China: USA, Russia, India
Russia: USA, Japan

**Dataframe 2 (id, available):**
USA: true
China: false
Russia: true
India: false
Japan: true

**Result Dataset should look like:**
(USA, China),
(USA, India)

My idea is to first explode the data set1, create new data frame (say, tempDF), add 2 new columns to it: targetAvailable, sourceAvailable and finally filter for targetAvailable = false and sourceAvailable = true to get the desired result data frame.

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
 val sourceDF = sourceData.toDF("targetId", "sourceId")
 val mappingDF = mappingData.toDF("id", "available")
 val tempDF = sourceDF.select(col("targetId"), 
                explode(col("sourceId")).as("source_id_split"))

 val resultDF = tempDF.select("targetId")
         .withColumn("targetAvailable", isAvailable(tempDF.col("targetId")))
         .withColumn("sourceAvailable", isAvailable(tempDF.col("source_id_split")))


 /*resultDF.select("targetId", "sourceId").
  filter(col("targetAvailable") === "true" and col("sourceAvailable") 
  === "false").show()*/


// udf to find the availability value for the given id from the mapping table
val isAvailable = udf((searchId: String) => {
val rows = mappingDF.select("available")
          .filter(col("id") === searchId).collect()

if (rows(0)(0).toString.equals("true")) "true" else "false"  })
```

Calling `isAvailable` UDF while calculating the `resultDF` throws me some weird exception. Am I doing something wrong? is there a better / simpler way to do this?

Comment: Hi Uday, welcome to SO. What have you already tried? 
Can you please show us the code you have and your current problem? It currently does not look like a problem you are having, but like a piece of homework you have. Thanks!

Comment: hello @regina_fallangi: thanks for pointing out. Edited the description and added my code.

Comment: "calling isAvailable UDF while calculating the resultDF throws me some weird exception. " -> Can you please post the "weird exception"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UDF, you are making reference to another dataframe, which is not possible, hence the "weird" exception you obtain.

You want to filter one dataframe based on values contained in another. What you need to do is a join on the `id` columns. Two joins actually in your case, one for the targets, one for the sources.

The idea to use `explode` however is very good. Here is a way to achieve what you want:

```scala
// generating data, please provide this code next time ;-)
val sourceDF = Seq("USA" ->  Seq("China", "Russia", "India", "Japan"),
                   "China" -> Seq("USA", "Russia", "India"),
                   "Russia" -> Seq("USA", "Japan"))
               .toDF("targetId", "sourceId")
val mappingDF = Seq("USA" -> true, "China" -> false,
                    "Russia" -> true, "India" -> false,
                    "Japan" -> true)
               .toDF("id", "available")

sourceDF
    // we can filter available targets before exploding.
    // let's do it to be more efficient.
    .join(mappingDF.withColumnRenamed("id", "targetId"), Seq("targetId"))
    .where('available)
    // exploding the sources
    .select('targetId, explode('sourceId) as "sourceId")
    // then we keep only non available sources
    .join(mappingDF.withColumnRenamed("id", "sourceId"), Seq("sourceId"))
    .where(! 'available)
    .select("targetId", "sourceId")
    .show(false)
```

which yields

```
+--------+--------+
|targetId|sourceId|
+--------+--------+
|USA     |China   |
|USA     |India   |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was exactly looking for. Thanks much!

Comment: Oli: here we are joining twice with mapping table once to filter out the target mappings and then to filter out the source mappings. just curious, is there a way to solve it using just one join?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your comment at the time. That actually depends. If both dataframes are large, I don't see any solution because since you are joining on two different columns, you need to shuffle the data differently to colocate matching keys. If one of them is small however (small enough to be broadcast), we could do better. Is that the case?